# Как добавить пункт List View из Activity в Fragment?

Tags: android-fragment, android, listview

Как добавит пункт `List View` из `Activity` в `Fragment`?

**Создал private void в MyActivity:**

```
private void AddObject(String var, String var2)
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> catList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> hm;

    Fragment frag1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.load_objects);
    ListView listView = (ListView) frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put(TITLE, var); // Название
    hm.put(DESCRIPTION, var2); // Описание

    catList.add(hm);

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(frag1.getActivity(), catList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TITLE, DESCRIPTION, /*ICON*/},
            new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, /*R.id.img*/ });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Когда пытаюсь вызвать - приложение вылетает.

**LOG:**

```
9506-19506/com.hss.realty E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com..*, PID: 19506
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com..**.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hss.realty.MyActivity.AddObject(MyActivity.java:129)
            at com.hss.realty.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:78)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5341)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Что-то на строке 129 у вас не определено (null).

Comment: ListView listView = (ListView) frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: getView() возвращает null

Comment: мда..

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>